# How to enable to change Permalinks for Individual Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have created CPT "Jobs" and I would like to display possibilities for publishers to change Permalinks for Individual Custom Post Type in the edit section. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean the post slugs or the archive URL?

Comment: i mean the post slugs

Comment: Did you add support for the `title`? Post types should have this by default if you can input a title.

Comment: Yes i add support for the title but still have same issue